# Confused about OpenWrt's Firewall Zone Settings Definition

Tags: networking, routing, openwrt, router

My router (which runs OpenWrt Attitude Adjustment 12.09) has a public IP address,
and my computer is in my LAN. 
So naturally I'm going to masquerade outbound (me → Internet) traffic
to make it possible to access the Internet.  My settings:

[image: Firewall Zone Settings]

Textually:

| Zone ⇒ Forwardings | Input | Output | Forwarding | Masquerading |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lan ⇒ wan | accept | accept | accept | (unchecked) |
| wan ⇒ lan | accept | accept | reject | **(checked)** |

If I **uncheck** `Masquerading` in the second line, I'll lose my access to the Internet. And through `iptables-save` I found that the `MASQUERADE` target for the chain `zone_nat_wan` in the table `nat` is gone.

So here's my question: doesn't “wan ⇒ lan” mean the traffic from WAN to LAN? 
If not, what does it mean?

Comment: Based on your image, I think you are doing something similar to me: trying to use the wifi as the wan. Could you add some comments as to what you had to do in the end to the firewall to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends(tm). The WAN Zone (WAN->LAN in your example) is about traffic from WAN to LAN for "Forward" (established connections), from LAN to WAN for "Output" and from WAN to LAN (all other packets) for "Input".

Masquerading is applied on outgoing packets of a specific interface by setting the source address of that packet to the interface address and using conntrack to save the state, therefore the developers opted to interpret this as "Masquerade WAN = Masquerade outgoing packets on the WAN interface". Of course one can argue that it would make more sense to enable masquerading on the LAN interface, since this is the network that is being masqueraded, so it's more a matter of perspective.